# How to treat a bonus for tax purposes if moving states

Tags: united-states, taxes, new-york

I moved from NY to a tax-free state in December of 2018. In January of 2019, I received a cash bonus from my employer. Despite not living in NY anymore, the company withheld NY state income taxes for that bonus. The argument is likely that the bonus was for services in 2018, even though it was not paid until 2019. Will I be able to file for a refund from NY for that tax that was withheld?

Comment: where was the work done that triggered the bonus?

Comment: Worked in NYC in 2018, bonus was paid in January of 2019 (could argue it was for work done in 2018, but its not like its perfectly clear). Did not switch companies, so working for same company in new state.

Comment: Normally the tax date is the date the payment was made, not the date the work was done.

Comment: Most states can tax your income if you live *or* work in the state. That fact that you moved doesn't change the fact that you work in NY.

Comment: To rephrase what chepner said, a nonresident of a state would generally still have to pay that state's taxes on income from that state.

Comment: @chepner Are we sure the op is still working in ny?  Maybe he's traveling to an office in the new state.

Comment: Are you commuting to an office in ny, or a new office in the new state?

Comment: Correct, I no longer work or live in NY. I moved states in 2018 and now work and live in a non income tax state. The bonus hit my account and was taxed by NY in January of 2019, even though I no longer worked or lived there. The bonus was technically for work primarily done in 2018 but was not paid until 2019, so not sure if it’s a tax income or accrual based rule for NY purposes.